# want to extract information from pdf with table

Tags: node.js, pdf, pdf-extraction, pdf-to-html

I want to extract marks from the table in the pdf. i tried converting it to excel but failed. i also tried converting it to html but the the marks are not being extracted properly.

my pdf with table looks like
[image: PDF]

i tried to convert pdf to html using pdf2html.

here's the code which i tried

```
export const convertToHtml = async (req, res) => {  
try {    
const html = await pdf2html.html('result.pdf');    
res.status(200).json({ message: html });  
} 
catch (error) 
{    
const errors = { backendError: String };    
errors.backendError = error;    
res.status(500).json(errors);  
}};
```

i want to extract the marks of the students based on their name/seat number.

Comment: Can someone please help me with this?